# Can't run docker-compose with java and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new in Docker. I try to run docker-compose with images java and mysql but I have error.

The stack trace of erorr is next:

```
app_1      | 2022-09-10 10:34:41.663  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app_1      | 2022-09-10 10:34:41.668  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
app_1      | 2022-09-10 10:34:41.690  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
app_1      | 
app_1      | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
app_1      | 2022-09-10 10:34:41.731 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
app_1      | 
app_1      | org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app_1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    ... 43 common frames omitted
app_1      | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
app_1      |    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:171) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar!/:2.7.2]
app_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
app_1      |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
app_1      |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
app_1      |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
app_1      |    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

My docker-compose.yml is next:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3333:8080'

  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - adminer
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
```

My Dockerfile is next:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 80
```

My application.properties in spring-boot project is next:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3333/football?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is the  `mysql:mysql-connector-java` that provides `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` included in the pom?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Update your build.gradle file or pom.xml file.

Comment: @Ensei then check if the final jar in the container contains the dependency by executing `jar -tvf app.jar | grep mysql` inside the container. May be some issue in packaging.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that docker image does not contain app dependencies (e.g. Jdbc Driver).

1. Check whether the dependencies are included in docker image as follows:

- Start docker image with bash instance:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash <docker-image-id>
```

- Navigate to app folder and check app dependencies (extract and check jar file if it is built with dependencies)

2. If this is the case, build docker image with dependencies, e.g. as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```